# Unable to run haproxy_exporter on localhost:9101

Tags: haproxy

I am using haproxy_exporter in prometheus which runs on default port 9101.
After configuring files i am not able to run this on default port.

Config file for haproxy:

```
frontend frontend
    bind :1234
    use_backend backend

backend backend
    server server 0.0.0.0:9000

frontend monitoring
    bind :1235
    no log
    stats uri /
    stats enable
```

Config file for prometheus

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s


  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'production'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080', 'localhost:8081']
        labels:
          group: 'production'

  - job_name: 'canary'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8082']
        labels:
          group: 'canary'

  - job_name: 'test'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9091']

  - job_name: 'test1'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9091']

  - job_name: 'test2'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9091']

  - job_name: 'haproxy'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9188']
```

Please, can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not setup stats on a `frontend` node, but on a `listener` (keyword **listen**, not <del>frontend</del>):

```
listen monitoring
    mode http
    bind *:1235
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats auth username:password
```

I strongly recommend that you also use a username/password to access you stats.

Finally, you can scrape data from haproxy with [haproxy_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/haproxy_exporter) with command:

```
haproxy_exporter -haproxy.scrape-uri="http://username:password@<haproxy-dns>:1235/?stats;csv"
```

If everything is fine with your setup, you should be able to query the haproxy exporter with this curl:

```
curl http://localhost:9101/metrics
```

And the output should contain:

> haproxy_up 1

If the ouput is `haproxy_up 0`, then there is a communication issue between `haproxy` and the `haproxy_exporter`, double check the `-haproxy.scrape-uri` value.

Comment: May be issue is OS dependant which OS are you in? HAproxy version is 1.7.2-1.